# Localhost giving wrong date in php

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the current date, for some reason it's giving me 2/12/2012, even though my computer clearly says its 2/29/2012.  I'm using XAMPP on my local machine.  Here is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$todaysDate = date("m/d/y");
$currentMonth = date("m");
$currentYear = date("y");
$currentDay = date("d");
```

Comment: Has the timezone on your computer been set properly? Maybe it's set at Greenwich.

Comment: Yup, set properly, Pacific Time Zone.

Comment: How do you see that its 2/12/2012? Do you output ``echo "$currentMont/$currentDay/$currentYear";``? Please share your output code. I don't think that it is a timezone problem. The wrong timezone would not explain an offset of several days.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$todaysDate=date('m/d/Y',time());
$currentMonth = date('m',time());
$currentYear = date('Y',time());
$currentDay = date('d',time());
```

Without timezone_set.